# A proof related to Quadratic Reciprocity Theorem

Tags: number-theory

**If $p$ & $q$ are distinct primes of the form $4K+3$ and $$x^2 \; \equiv \; p(\;mod \;q)$$ has no solution then prove that $$x^2 \; \equiv \; q(\;mod \;p)$$ has two solutions**

*I see that this statement  somewhat resembles the Quadratic reciprocity theorem which goes in similar way that one of these congruence is solvable and other is not*

> How can I prove that the congruence has exactly two solutions

Comment: $$\left(\dfrac pq\right)=(-1)^{(2k+1)(2k_1+1)}\left(\dfrac qp\right)=-\left(\dfrac qp\right)$$ therefore we have $$-1=-\left(\dfrac qp\right)\iff\left(\dfrac qp\right)=1$$ Thus $q$ is  quadratic residue modulo $p$.

Comment: To conclude that there are exactly two solutions, note that $x^2\equiv q\equiv a^2\pmod p$ iff $x\equiv\pm a\pmod p$

Comment: I think your reasoning shows (there are) two solutions, not "exactly" two of them. Anyway to finish correctly is easy. Regards.

Comment: @Piquito: Noting that $a^2\equiv b^2\pmod p\iff a\equiv\pm b$ concludes that WLOG $a\in\left\{0,1,\ldots,\frac{p-1}2\right\}$ is unique, so $\pm a$ are the only 2 solutions modulo $p$.

Comment: Hi Prasun: Easy, I told you.